# Vscode not showing java annotation processor warnings in source code

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, annotation-processing

I am developing a java project requiring the use of annotation processors using maven in VS Code. I set up two maven projects, one containing the main project and one containing the annotations. When trying to debug my processor I realised that no warning or error printed to  the messager was showing up in my source code.

#### Here is my example processor:

```java
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.hein.annotation.ResourceID")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_19)
@AutoService(Processor.class)
public class ResourceProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for (TypeElement annotation : annotations) {
            Set<? extends Element> elements = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(annotation);
            
            elements.stream().forEach(e -> processingEnv.getMessager().printError("oops!!", e));
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

I made sure to compile and install my annotation project and even got the errors and warnings in the console when compiling my main project manually with `mvn clean compile`. I'm using the standard [Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) and it's working for other annotations.

Comment: what do you mean by "showing in source code"? Can you more clearly explain/describe what you expect to see?

Comment: What error are you getting? What is your desired effect?   Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I want to see a squiggly line under my annotation or annotated element in my code editor window indicating a warning or an error similar to an unused variable or a syntax error respectively.

Comment: What does `it's working for other annotations` mean? Have you already configured Pomxml correctly? Whether the local Maven repository is correct and whether the dependencies have been added, etc.